# Global VC++ Directories for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

i tried in the file C:\Users\DrHanner\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <IncludePath>D:\!\c++\include;$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
    <LibraryPath>D:\!\c++\libs;$(LibraryPath)</LibraryPath>
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup />
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

and

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
    <IncludePath>D:\!\c++\include;$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
    <LibraryPath>D:\!\c++\libs;$(LibraryPath)</LibraryPath>
  <PropertyGroup />
```

the error message is element includepath under the element importgroup is unrecognised.

doesn't work either,
and otherWindow->propertyManager doesn't exist.

maybe it is because i have a trial version ...

Comment: Why do you have a folder named `!`? Because I think that's the problem. Maybe try escaping it? Or putting it in quotes?

Comment: Always best to use the IDE to make changes like that.  View > Other Windows > Property Manager.  Right-click Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User > Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories setting and add the directory.  Then File > Save.  You'll see the affect it has on the file, doesn't look like that.

Comment: the folder "!" is the first in aphabetical listing ;) rakete